Enable Token Bearer functionality
In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I've configured JWT authentication and added Swagger for API documentation. I've only applied the [Authorize] attribute to specific endpoints, such as the /logout endpoint, but when I open Swagger, it shows that all endpoints require a JWT Bearer token, even those that should be publicly accessible (e.g., /register and /login).
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: 'Bearer {token}'"
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    });
});

    [HttpPost("register")]
    [SwaggerOperation(summary: "Register a new user")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterDto userDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Map RegisterDto to User using AutoMapper
        var user = _mapper.Map<User>(userDto);

        var result = await _userService.RegisterUserAsync(user, userDto.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest(result.Errors);
        }

        return Ok();
    }



    // POST: api/auth/login
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto userDto)
    {
        var token = await _userService.LoginUserAsync(userDto.Email, userDto.Password);
        if (token != null)
        {
            return Ok(new { Token = token });
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }


    [HttpPost("logout")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        return Ok(new { message = "Logged out successfully." });
    }

}

To Require Token only in logout endpoint

It looks like you have the same concern as this case, could you please take a look at it?
